# SceneKit - Render node always with same screen space size

Tags: ios, 3d, rendering, scenekit, metal

How can I render a node so that it has constant screen space no matter how far the node is from the camera?
For example: I have a plane that should be 100x100 pixels on the screen wherever you place it inside the SCNScene.

Solutions that I have tried:

1. Setting right scale depending on the distance from a camera on each render frame (this works, but I am looking for more elegant solution)
2. Using pointSize and minimumPointSize in geometry element (this is not working for me, maybe I am doing something wrong ?)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an orthographic projection. On your SCNCamera, set `usesOrthographicProjection = true`.